# How to create a WebHook with WCF to GitHub Enterprise?

Tags: wcf, github, enterprise

I wanna create a WebHook to integrate with a server GitHub Enterprise. I want to use WCF to create this service, but I don't found a tutorial or step by step. This is my first work with WebHooks, and I did not found the model of the structure of the service to integrate with GitHub.

Anybody have a solution, example or the way to developer this? What methods, parameters and names I need use? The documentation of GitHub is not clear to me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The methodology to create webhooks in the UI on earlier versions of GitHub Enterprise is very similar to GitHub.com and is now identical on GitHub Enterprise 11.10.340 and later.

Using the UI is a case of browsing to the repository in question, select the "Settings" icon on the right, select "Service Hooks" and configure the appropriate hook. (The wording has changed slightly in GitHub Enterprise 11.10.340 to match what you see on GitHub.com).

If there isn't already a predefined service, a standard "WebHook URLs" hook should do the trick.  This will POST the push payload to the URL you enter here.

You can also create the webhook using the API. If you're not running GitHub Enterprise 11.10.340 or later, you can refer to our archived documentation at https://developer.github.com/enterprise/11.10.320/, specifically https://developer.github.com/enterprise/11.10.320/v3/repos/hooks/ for how to use the API to create a webhook.  If you're running GitHub Enterprise 11.10.340 or later the documentation at https://developer.github.com/webhooks/ applies to these versions of GitHub Enterprise.

You'd then need to ensure the recipient of this POST knows how to process the payload and act upon it.

A good service to use to check the payload from any webhook is http://requestb.in/.